# Preventing ListView to download images again and again when View is reused

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview

I have tried about every other example in the net, but couldn't seem to solve this problem. I have a ListView with one ImageView and one TextView. Images are loaded asynchronously into ImageView. But since android seems to reuse the Views, getView() is called frequently and same images are download again and again. So I tried to use ViewHolder. The code is as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.imageDesc.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.imageDesc.setText(dataList.get(position).getImageDesc());

            //Loads image asynchronously into the imageView
            ImageLoader.loadImage(holder.image, ((ListViewItem)getItem(position)).getImageLink());

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageDesc;
    ImageView image;

}
```

This seems to download the code only once. But if i scroll the ListView the items are randomly placed and shown in ListView. 
What's the correct way to display images asynchronously in ListView without these issues?? Am I missing something?

Comment: have you condidered using universal image loader?? It will download a image only once and you can either disc cache the image or memory cache it Also consider storing the bitmap in a arraylist and showing it from it

Comment: I used Picaso, and it worked. I wanted to know what these libraries are implementing.
If a store bitmaps in a arraylist wont my app eat up too much memeory?? @IllegalArgument

Comment: @MilanMaharjan they just use clever caching strategies. You'd better read some source code.

Comment: yes storing it in arraylist eats up lot of memory the library like picaso use a unique identifier to identify a bitmap in case of UIL it is the url appended by the size of the bitmap you should consider lazyloading images one way or another

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
     holder.imageDesc.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.imageDesc.setText(dataList.get(position).getImageDesc());

                //Loads image asynchronously into the imageView
                ImageLoader.loadImage(holder.image, ((ListViewItem)getItem(position)).getImageLink());
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: as @Rod_Algonquin said, it downloads image again and again.